# Return value for JsonArray

Tags: arrays, json, spring-mvc, grails, groovy

What is the return value for `JSONArray` if the code as like this

```
public JSONArray saveHCPMapping(String parameters, String appId, String password)
{
//your logic
  try{
     // some logic
      try{
          for(){
             //some logic
                }
          }catch(){
             //some logic
          }
          if(){
              for(){
                    if(){
                        //some code
                        }else{
                        //some code and some more if else conditions
                         }
         }catch(){
            //some code
           return jsonArray;
           }
          return jsonArray;
       }
```

Comment: No idea what you are asking for. The method signature tells you that the method is supposed to return an object of class JSONArray. In that sense: please try to rephrase your question to make it clear what you are asking for. I really dont get it.

Comment: I have added the return value for the closure

Answer (score 1):

In Groovy, if you do not use the return keyword, then the last line of your method body is used for the return statement.

In the example you have provided, there is no method body and therefore Groovy will return an empty JSONArray.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `return` statement in the body of the method which tells you the value of the `JSONArray`.